# How to import Datetime column from SQL Server to Hive using Sqoop

Tags: hive, timestamp, sqoop

I am trying to import data from SQL Server to Hive using Sqoop. When I import the datetime column it's ignores the values like below.

SQL Server - 2021-02-10 10:30:00.000
Hive       - 2021-02-10 10:30:00.0

Sqoop ignores all the zero after final dot and keep only one zero. But if we have actual value then sqoop import actual value correctly as below.

SQL Server - 2021-02-10 10:30:10.865
Hive       - 2021-02-10 10:30:10.865

I see this issue even when I am using sqoop eval.

Sqoop import --connect  --user-name root --password root --table customer --hive-import --hive-database wholesale --hive-table customer_stg --hive-overwrite -- --schema dbo

Answer (score 0):

This is quite normal behavior. Last zeros in milliseconds part are not significant in the timestamp. If you are loading timestamp in Hive from string like this `2021-02-10 10:30:00.120`, then select it, you will see `2021-02-10 10:30:00.12`.

**It is actually exactly the same timestamp because `0.120 = 0.12`, only it's string representation is different in different tools.**

Timestamps don't have a strict string format associated with them, Hive supports 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS', fractions of seconds part is optional. If a specific format is expected, it needs to be converted into a STRING with an explicit format.